# userinfo command having trouble with game activity

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I just asked a question for something similar to this today, however, I got the answer and came across a new problem. I am creating a user info command for a discord bot, and if the user is not playing a game, the bot will crash.

this link contains images of the console log when a user is in-game and when a user is not in-game. You just have to read the descriptions of the images. https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7ywt.jpg

code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const moment = require('moment');

module.exports = {
    name: "userinfo",
    aliases: ['ui', 'user', 'uinfo'],
    category: "info",
    description: "shows information of the user you mentioned",
    usage: "[command | alias]",
    run: async (client, message, args) => {
        
    const user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;
    const member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.member;
    const joinDiscord = moment(user.createdAt).format('llll');
    const joinServer = moment(user.joinedAt).format('llll');
    
    var presence = user.presence.activities.filter(x=>x.type === "PLAYING")
    console.log(presence);
    
    
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#724e72')
    .setTitle(`**Information for** ${user.tag}`)
    .setAuthor(`${message.author.tag}`, message.author.displayAvatarURL())
    .setDescription('Shows information for mentioned user')
    .setThumbnail(user.displayAvatarURL())
    .addField(`${user.tag}`, `${user}`, true)
    //.addField("ID:", `${user.id}`, true)
    .addField("Nickname:", `${member.displayName}`, true)
    .addField("Status:", `${user.presence.status}`, true)
    //.addField("In Server", message.guild.name, true)
    .addField("Game:", `${presence}`, true)
    .addField("Bot:", `${user.bot}`, true)
    .addField("Joined The Server On:", `${moment.utc(message.member.joinedAt).format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY")}`)
    .addField("Account Created On:", `${moment.utc(user.createdAt).format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY")}`, true) 
    .addField("Roles:", member.roles.cache.map(r => '`'+r.name+'`').slice(0,-1))
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter('a')
    
    message.channel.send(embed);
    }
}
```

If anybody can help out, thank you. I have not used discord.js or JavaScript in at least a year so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your first 2 images links do not work

Comment: sorry about that. can you see if this link works?
https://imgur.com/a/ZLL24FY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the user is not in a game then `presence` is an empty array. When an empty array is stringified then it is converted into an empty string. This means that when you do this

```js
    .addField("Game:", `${presence}`, true)
```

it is adding a field with an empty value to the embed as indicated in the error.  You can either do something like this:

```js
/* ... */
.addField("Game:", `${presence}`||'None', true)
```

or just check if `presence` is empty before adding it to the embed like this

```js
/* ... */
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#724e72')
    .setTitle(`**Information for** ${user.tag}`)
    .setAuthor(`${message.author.tag}`, message.author.displayAvatarURL())
    .setDescription('Shows information for mentioned user')
    .setThumbnail(user.displayAvatarURL())
    .addField(`${user.tag}`, `${user}`, true)
    //.addField("ID:", `${user.id}`, true)
    .addField("Nickname:", `${member.displayName}`, true)
    .addField("Status:", `${user.presence.status}`, true)
    //.addField("In Server", message.guild.name, true)
    if (presence) embed.addField("Game:", `${presence}`, true)
    embed.addField("Bot:", `${user.bot}`, true)
    .addField("Joined The Server On:", `${moment.utc(message.member.joinedAt).format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY")}`)
    .addField("Account Created On:", `${moment.utc(user.createdAt).format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY")}`, true) 
    .addField("Roles:", member.roles.cache.map(r => '`'+r.name+'`').slice(0,-1))
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter('a')
/* ... */
```